# Laravel / Eloquent : hasManyThrough question

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:
Contract, with id
Contract_User, with contract_id and user_id
User, with id

I'm trying to use hasManyThrought to get the User information when I have a contract, but I'm having trouble.

Is it possible? 
Thanks

Comment: That's not a `hasManyThrough()`, that's a simple `belongsToMany()`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.  When you have 2 models and a pivot between them, it's a `many-to-many`. Post your models (`Contract` and `User`), and your relationships (In `Contract`, `public function users()` and int `User`, `public function contracts()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Tim Lewis. I think this is just a "simple" [BelongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Depending on what your models look like, here is an example of what they could/should look like.

If you are using something other than the default foreign keys, you'll need to provide those column(s) as extra parameters. You can find more on that in the link above as well. Hope this helps!

**User.php**

```
/**
 * The contracts that belong to the user.
 */
public function contracts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contract');
}
```

**Contract.php**

```
/**
 * The users that belong to the contract.
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Then somewhere in your controller, you'd get to the user's contracts by:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->contracts as $contract) {
    // $contract->name;
}
```